# Java - Learning to use MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

I'm trying to learn how to use MigLayout. Here is what I have, and it looks like what I want it to look like:

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
JPanel authorsPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "[]20[][]", "[][][][][][]"));


JTable authorsTable = new JTable(authorstableModel);

// Configure labels
JLabel firstNameL = new JLabel("First Name:");
JLabel middleNameL = new JLabel("Middle Name:");
JLabel lastNameL = new JLabel("Last Name:");
JLabel blurbL = new JLabel("Blurb/Bio:");

// Configure text fields
firstName = new JTextField("No Selection", 20);
firstName.setEditable(false);
firstName.setForeground(Color.gray);
middleName = new JTextField("No Selection", 20);
middleName.setEditable(false);
middleName.setForeground(Color.gray);
lastName = new JTextField("No Selection", 20);
lastName.setEditable(false);
lastName.setForeground(Color.gray);
blurb = new JTextArea("No Selection", 10, 40);
blurb.setEditable(false);
blurb.setForeground(Color.gray);
blurb.setLineWrap(true);

// Add components to authorsPanel
authorsPanel.add(new JScrollPane(authorsTable), "span 1 6");
authorsPanel.add(firstNameL);
authorsPanel.add(firstName, "wrap");
authorsPanel.add(middleNameL);
authorsPanel.add(middleName, "wrap");
authorsPanel.add(lastNameL);
authorsPanel.add(lastName, "wrap");
authorsPanel.add(blurbL);
authorsPanel.add(new JScrollPane(blurb), "span 2 2");
```

I feel as though I'm not really doing it correctly. It seems to make no difference whether I make a component "span 1 6" or "span 1 4" which is disconcerting. Also, the blurb JTextArea has a size that is determined when it is initiated and, again, seems to have no response in sizing to the MigLayout stuff, it only effects positioning.

I want to learn how to have more control over what I am doing with MigLayout in this scenario, as I was having a bunch of problems even beginning to make this work. I also want to do it the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

First tip: setting it to `debug` lets you see the areas that the MigLayout has declared and how components are spread over them. This might be very useful in cases like this.

The `authorsPanel`, I think you want it to set to `spany`. The default is to fill up all the available space.
Same for the `JScrollPane(blurp)`, that should be `spany 2`.

You said you had a problem is getting is to the correct size, but not what that should be compared to the picture, so I cannot give you any tips on that. You probably want to look into first bit of code, where you declare the initial MigLayout:

```
JPanel authorsPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "[]20[][]", "[][][][][][]"));
```

This is the place to describe how elements should `grow`/`fill` or otherwise look.

Take a look at: http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/whitepaper.html and http://www.miglayout.com/cheatsheet.html